# How can I power off my iphone and clean out all running applications?

Tags: iphone, ios7

On my iPhone 5s running IOS 7.1.1, when holding down the power button, and sliding the 'slide to power off' slider, the phone turns completely off. But when I power it back on, all of my apps that I had running before are still running! How do I power off my iphone and clean out all running applications?

I want to troubleshoot some issues I've been having with non-responsiveness in safari browsing, and inability to 'hang up' after a call (the button does not press).

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Apple hardware.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot doesn't close the apps. It's because many of those apps are not really running, even though they appear in the multi-task bar. iOS removes most of them from RAM (system memory) and only a very few of the app's functions are left running - playing audio for example.

The remaining apps that 'appear' to be running simply have their state ('context') stored so that the app can be reloaded in exactly the same state as when it was suspended. Those context files are not cleared by a reboot, so the apps still appear in the multi-task bar.

The only way to delete the context file - and hence remove its app from the multi-task bar is to **manually close the app by pressing an icon in the multi-task bar** until they all start to jiggle and then pressing the upper left hand corner of the app's icon. That tells iOS to delete the app's context file and so it no longer appears in the multi-task bar.

Comment: 1) A reboot does close apps. 2) Your description to force-quit an app and remove the icon from the "recently-used-app list" is for iOS 6 and earlier, not iOS 7 or later.